# Calling Groovy script from PowerShell and have access to Jenkins internals

Tags: powershell, jenkins, groovy

I have a build system that runs off of PowerShell scripts.

I want these scripts to be able to do things like change the `description` and `keepLog` settings of the current build.

The only way I currently know of setting those is with the groovy plugin and the *Execute system Groovy script*.

Is it possible for a PowerShell script, called from Jenkins, to call a Groovy script that has access to the Jenkins internal objects?

If not, is there any other way to access the internal Jenkins objects from a PowerShell script?

I am currently calling the PowerShell script from an *Execute Windows Batch Command* build step.

Answer (score 0):

You can change or add to `jenkins/jobs/<job name>/builds/<build no.>/build.xml`:

```
<build>
  ...
  <description>Description</description>
  <keepLog>true</keepLog>
  ...
</build>
```

I experienced lately that `build.xml` is created after the end of the build only but this shouldn't be a problem for `description` and `keepLog`. You can create a downstream job that:

- is parameterized
- is triggered by the upstream job
- receives [JOB_NAME and BUILD_NO](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables) from the upstream job
- executes the script

There is a [`Build`](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Build.html) class in Jenkins' API inheriting `Run.setDescription()` and `Run.keepLog()` but I don't know whether it's possible to access it from outside of Jenkins. I always used Grovvy scripts inside Jenkins.

Comment: You can try running groovy scripts posting them via [HTTP](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Script+Console) or [Jenkins CLI jar](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI).